# Acolhendo variável de sistema e enviando para dropdown

Tags: javascript, java, html

boa tarde.

Estou ainda no caminho da programação com html e javascript.
Pesquisei bastante sobre o que eu quero aqui. Alguns chegaram próximos, mas não ao ponto do que pretendo.

O cenário:
Tenho um sistema java (por navegador, especificamente o I.E.) que com uma aba que envia um código para um auto-completar de url dentro de um iframe para outro sistema. Ex:

> - Abro a aba do sistema e ele completa com uma variável pré-definida: http://srv/integ.aspx?=**&<codigo_produto>**
> - Ele substitui a variável **&<codigo_produto>** por um ID numérico. Ex: 154441

Agora tenho dois sistemas que precisam receber o mesmo código, no entanto na mesma aba para que eu escolha qual abrir. Quero fazer isso por um dropdown. Então criei um html simples para fazer essa seleção no lugar do link pré-definido acima.
Precisamente gostaria de que o HTML por meio de js acolhesse essa variável que iria para a URL.

Há algum método para que o html receba essa variável de sistema e jogue ela para os itens da seleção dropdown?

Não sei se fui muito claro, mas alguém poderia me dar uma idéia?
Obrigado!

UPDATE: lembrei que um dos sistemas recebe a ID no meio do link. Ex:

http://out/apg/acceptcom= **&<codigo_produto>** inner&scope=repo&sortField=null

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma interessante seria voce colocar esse valor no localStorage, dessa maneira fica mais limpa sua URL e voce consegue resgatar esse dado de maneira mais simples.

Guardando item: `localStorage.setItem('localName',suaVariavel);`

Resgatando item: `localStorage.getItem('localName')`

Removendo item :  `localStorage.removeItem('localName');`

Boa sorte.